# TypeScript Type Inference of Nested React Component Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm struggling to correctly annotate the following React component with TypeScript:

```
<MyComponent input={[Component, props]} />
```

`input`: Should be an array in which the first member is a React Functional Component and the second member is an object containing its respective props.

For this example, let's assume `Component` to be defined as follows:

```
interface IComponentProps {
    data: number;
}

const Component: FC<IComponentProps> = ({data}) => {
    return <span>{data}</span>;
};
```

This is what I have so far for `MyComponent`:

```
interface IDefault {
    [k: string]: unknown;
}

type TInput<T extends IDefault = IDefault> = [FC<T>, T];

interface IComponentProps {
    input: TInput;
}

const MyComponent: FC<IComponentProps> = ({input}) => {
    const [Component, props] = input;

    return <Component {...props} />;
};
```

Unfortunately, when using the component, like this:

```
<MyComponent input={[Component, {data: 1}]} />
```

I get: `Property 'data' is missing in type 'IDefault' but required in type 'IOtherComponentProps'`

Which suggests me that TypeScript isn't inferencing the props, so it is using the default value.

To give more information about the expected behaviour, I would expect, for example, in this case:

```
<MyComponent input={[Component, {data: true}]} />
```

To get an error as `data` should be a `number`.

I've also tried the following type alternative (among others):

```
type TInput<T extends FC = FC<{[k: string]: unknown}>> = [
    T,
    ComponentPropsWithoutRef<T>
];
```

But without success.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
type RendererProps<M> = {
  input: [React.ComponentType<M>, M];
};

const MyComponentRenderer = <M,>({ input }: RendererProps<M>) => {
  const [Component, props] = input;
  return <Component {...props} />;
};
```

Looks like it works:

```
const TakesAFooProp = (props: { foo: string }) => {
  return <>{foo}</>;
};

// works
<MyComponentRenderer input={[TakesAFooProp, { foo: 'bar' }]} />;

// fails - foo is not assignable to number
<MyComponentRenderer input={[TakesAFooProp, { foo: 9 }]} />;

// fails - property foo is missing in type
<MyComponentRenderer input={[TakesAFooProp, { bar:'baz' }]} />;
```